# Angular service keeps saying NullInjectorError: No provider for anotherService

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I created simple angular service

```
@Injectable()

export class someHandler {

    constructor(
        public anotherService: anotherService,
    ) {}
...
```

Problem is that when I use this service in some component it keeps saying that `NullInjectorError: No provider for anotherService` but I cant use `providers: []` inside service right? So what can I do? Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you add the service in your module providers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure because you didn't provide the module.ts but looks like anotherService is not part of the same module as someHandler.

In the module where you defines `providers : ['someHandler']`

You must import the module that include anotherService ->  `imports: [..., anotherServiceModule]`

Answer (score 0):

We must tell Angular to instantiate `AnotherService` to be available (instatiated) before `SomeHandler`.
So in your module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Component1Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [AnotherService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Like this, `AnotherService` is provided to the entire application as **singleton** and it is already instantiated.